# How would you represent a dropdown menu in ARIA?

Tags: drop-down-menu, wai-aria

I am adding ARIA tags to my code and I was wondering what is the right way of adding a `role` attribute to a dropdown menu?

Is it `role="option"` or `role="combobox"` or `role="listbox"`?

Answer (score 0):

Use role=combobox for dropdown.

See example here:

http://test.cita.illinois.edu/aria/combobox/index.php
http://test.cita.illinois.edu/aria/combobox/combobox1.php